Is this question about the detriments of ergonomic mice in gaming suitable?
I want to ask a question about how (wireless) ergonomic mice can be compared to more traditional (wireless) gaming mice. I’m specially asking in a competitive FPS (think Valorant or The Finals) aspect.
I’m not sure if there would be any detriments, but it seems like a vaguely subjective question, so just checking first.

Rather than asking about the detriments (or benefits), you could ask for a comparison in a more neutral way: "How do ergonomic mice compare to traditional mice in terms of gaming?"

@Robotnik Would it be fine to add the part about competitive gaming, where things like aim and tracking matter?

Sure, questions about competitive play are on-topic. Just note that competitive play is (naturally) a bit niche compared to regular/casual multiplayer questions. You may also be helped by ProSettings' Mice list - note however they use the term "Ergonomic" in a different way, pertaining to shape rather than standard vs vertical hand alignment.

If worded properly, I believe this would be an ok question.  For instance, there are objective, quantitative comparisons that can be made, like number of thumb buttons, DPI configurability (including on the fly DPI adjustments), input lag for wireless mice in particular, etc.  Of course there will also be things that are measurable but depend heavily on the user, such as time to aim and aiming precision.  As an example, a trackball is generally much more precise, but also takes longer to aim.

While some things can be compared, things such as mouse buttons and input lag can vary a lot between mice. Wouldn’t this be too random and dependent on the mouse for an answer?

@Daemons Asking to compare particular models is outside this site's scope, I think, simply because it is too close to product recommendation, subjective, and specific (and would almost require in-depth reviewing). But comparing models, like in the question you're proposing, should be valid, and here we can compare the amount of mouse buttons (larger is better :). Mouse lag indeed seems too model-dependent a metric, though, but it can be good to point out in a comprehensive answer that it should be as low a number as possible (esp. in competitive FPS gaming).
